# UITabBarItem memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have an issue with this code in iOS9, this codes causes a memory leak each 
time it is called. I found this leak in instruments and the iOS function that seems to be leaking is [UITabBarButton initWithImage:selectedImage:label:withInsets:].

```
    UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBarLibrary.items objectAtIndex:0];
    item0.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarIcon1.png"];
```

Anyone else have this issue or have a way to work around it? Basically the code is switching the icon for the tab bar depending on the situation nothing complicated.

Comment: also experienced that

Answer (score 0):

I set any existing image to nil before setting the new one.

```
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBarLibrary.items objectAtIndex:0];
item0.image = nil;
item0.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarIcon1.png"];
```

This enables ARC to free up memory used by any existing image.

Comment: Still gives memory leak for me even with nil.